# is it possible to convert uploadcollection's object into a xstring?

Tags: javascript, upload, sapui5

Using the sapui5 uploadcollection to upload files in the frontend and then sending them through ajax with a post request...

I need to know how to convert te returned object from the uploadcollection control into a xstring, so then I can send that xstring (that contains the file content) To a sap gateway by using ajax post method.

Any idea how could I do this?

Right now I'm sending files by using the uploadcollection, once I upload an attachment, the control returns an object that represents the file content.

I'm trying to make this object a xstring by using filereader:

```
                                                        //obtiene archivo
                                                        var file = files[i];

                                                        //Convierte archivo en binario
                                                        var reader = new FileReader();
                                                        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {

                                                            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
                                                            var base64 = btoa(binaryString);
                                                            var base64file; 

                                                            if(typeof base64file == "undefined" || typeof base64file == null){
                                                                base64file = base64; 
                                                            }else{
                                                              base64file = base64file +'new'+base64;
                                                            }
                                                        };
                                                        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

                                                        console.log(file)
```

But this work only with files of type image, the others like pdf, .doc etc etc give the following error when I try to send them with ajax.

"The Data Services Request could not be understood due to malformed syntax".

Any idea how can I send convert these files into a xstring data?

Comment: Please fix that indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by filling an array everytime that a file was uploaded through the control,

```
                    change: function(oEvent) {


                        //Get file content
                        file = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];

                        //Prepare data for slug
                        fixname = file.name;
                        filename = fixname.substring(0, fixname.indexOf("."));
                        extension = fixname.substring(fixname.indexOf(".") + 1);

                        //fill array with uploaded file
                        var fileData = {
                            file: file,
                            filename: filename,
                            extension: extension
                        }
                        fileArray.push(fileData);

                    },
```

and then I did a loop over that array to post every single file I keept there by using ajax method post.

```
                                                $.each(fileArray, function(j, valor) {

                                                    //get file
                                                    file = fileArray[j].file;

                                                    //get file lenght
                                                    var numfiles = fileArray.length;


                                                    //Convert file to binary
                                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); 
                                                    reader.onload = function(evt) {
                                                        fileString = evt.target.result; 

                                                        //get and make slug
                                                        filename = fileArray[j].filename;
                                                        extension = fileArray[j].extension;
                                                        slug = documento + '/' + filename + '/' + extension;


                                                        //User url service
                                                        var sUrlUpload = "sap url";
                                                        runs++;

                                                        //Post files
                                                        jQuery.ajax({});
                                                    }
                                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example. Hope this helps.

**View**

```
<u:FileUploader change="onChange" fileType="pdf" mimeType="pdf" buttonText="Upload" />
```

**Controller**

```
convertBinaryToHex: function(buffer) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), function(x) {
            return ("00" + x.toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join("");
    },


onChange: function(oEvent){
    var that = this;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var raw = e.target.result;
        var hexString = that.convertBinaryToHex(raw).toUpperCase(); 
        // DO YOUR THING HERE            
    };

    reader.onerror = function() {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error occured when uploading file");
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
},
```